# How can I optimize this query and decrease its execution time

Tags: mysql, sql, performance

I have A query:

```
select      * 
from        `ads_fact` 
inner join  `dim_make`  on  `dim_make`.`make_id` = `ads_fact`.`make_id` 
inner join  `dim_model` on  `dim_model`.`model_id` = `ads_fact`.`model_id` 
inner join  `dim_state` on  `dim_state`.`state_id` = `ads_fact`.`state_id` 
inner join  `dim_source` on `dim_source`.`source_id` = `ads_fact`.`source_id` 
inner join  `dim_fuel_type` on `dim_fuel_type`.`fuel_type_id` = `ads_fact`.`fuel_type_id`
inner join  `dim_body_type` on `dim_body_type`.`body_type_id` = `ads_fact`.`body_type_id` 
where       1=1 
&&          date_time >= DATE_SUB(CURDATE(), INTERVAL 14 DAY) 
&&          ad_status=0 
order by    ad_id DESC 
limit 20 
offset 0
```

i tried few things but its response time is still above 7 seconds can any one help me optimize this query.

Comment: Please make some effort to format your query.

Comment: hi gordon how should i do it ?

Comment: How is this query running?  `&&` is not valid syntax.  `And` is.

Comment: @Siyual MySQL works in mysterious ways.

Comment: its working for me :)

Comment: i have 1 million plus records and its giving 11 sec response time

Comment: My initial thoughts are make sure the fields in your WHERE and ON conditions are appropriately indexed.

Comment: at the first look, I saw many tables and the select      * . Do you really need of all columns from all the tables? If don't, try to specify just the columns that you need!

Comment: What table is `date_time` in?

Comment: Did Slight change in condition and time improved by 4 second

Comment: change is : where       1=1 &&          ad_status=0  && year>2009 
&&          date_time >= DATE_SUB(CURDATE(), INTERVAL 14 DAY)

Comment: Still struggling with the 1=1 bit :-/

Comment: @NigelRen `1=1` is always true, so many people use it in order to only put 'real' predicates after `AND` clauses.  The main idea behind it is that it's much easier to comment out an `AND` line, than the `WHERE` (because you'll have to re-type `WHERE` or re-order your predicates), when you're going through testing.  SO has many good posts about it, but that's the gist.

Answer (score 0):

A couple of things you can do:

1. Avoid using functions in queries - use a variable before the query, and then use the variable in your WHERE clause

`SET @threshold_date = DATE_SUB(CURDATE(), INTERVAL 14 DAY);
SELECT ....
.....
WHERE date_time >= @threshold_date`

2. Make sure you have indexes on the appropriate columns - the ones on which you do JOIN and WHERE (date_time, ad_status, make_id, model_id, state_id, ...)

Comment: Specific date is not possible in my case because it has to show 14 days old record each day

Comment: @fahadshaikh that is fine. The temp variable is set everytime you execute the query. The way you have written it, SQL will get the current date for each row (assuming you don't have an index on date_time column). If you extract it on top, you will get the current time once.

Comment: In some situations (I don't know about this one), the Optimizer does a worse job with `@var` than with a constant expression.

Comment: @RickJames I am not too much into SQL optimizers, but is `DATE_SUB(CURDATE(), INTERVAL 14 DAY)` considered a constant expression?

Comment: Yes, the MySQL optimizer sees that it is constant _at the time of executing the query_.  So, it will pre-compute it and (effectively) do `WHERE date_time >= "2017-05-11"` (or whatever).

Comment: So, in _this situation_ I recommend against using `@var`.  There are _other situations_, such as parameterizing a lot of SQL, where `@var` is at least more convenient.

Comment: For your #2:  each of the `dim_` tables needs an index, not (in _this_ case) the `_fact` table.

Comment: Good to know - I have always followed the principal "no functions in where clauses". Could you back this up with a bit of a further reading material?

Answer (score 0):

The optimizer probably isn't handling this very well.  Making the assumption that all filters are coming from the `ads_fact` table...  Try creating a filter table first:

```
CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE IF NOT EXISTS temp1 AS (
  SELECT      * 
  FROM        `ads_fact`
  WHERE       1=1 
  AND         year > 2009 
  AND         date_time >= DATE_SUB(CURDATE(), INTERVAL 14 DAY)
  AND         ad_status=0 
  ORDER BY    ad_id DESC 
  LIMIT 20 
  OFFSET 0
)
```

Then join it back to the other tables:

```
SELECT      * 
FROM        temp1 
INNER JOIN  `dim_make`  ON `dim_make`.`make_id` = temp1.`make_id` 
INNER JOIN  `dim_model` ON `dim_model`.`model_id` = temp1.`model_id` 
INNER JOIN  `dim_state` ON `dim_state`.`state_id` = temp1.`state_id` 
INNER JOIN  `dim_source` ON `dim_source`.`source_id` = temp1.`source_id` 
INNER JOIN  `dim_fuel_type` ON `dim_fuel_type`.`fuel_type_id` = temp1.`fuel_type_id`
INNER JOIN  `dim_body_type` ON `dim_body_type`.`body_type_id` = temp1.`body_type_id`
```

Basically, this will guarantee that the optimizer does all the filtering on the smallest possible set of records.  Then the filtered set is joined back to the other tables. It's highly likely that your current query is completing all of the joins, then filtering, ordering, and limiting (or otherwise doing things in an inefficient order, because it can't come up with a good plan).

Comment: Rather than using a user-defined temp table; use a "derived" table:  `FROM ( SELECT ... ) as temp1 INNER JOIN ...`

Comment: Also, the optimizer won't guarantee that the final order will be 'correct', so need to add an extra `ORDER BY` on the final/outer `SELECT`.

Comment: Adding `year>2009` adds a serious wrinkle in performance.  How many other variations do we need to account for?  Is this an open-ended UI to filter on lots of different things?  If so, the Question need to say so !!

Comment: @RickJames You can't use an `ORDER BY` in a derived table, and he needs to `LIMIT` in the temp table or he won't gain much if any performance.  And yes, he should add an `ORDER BY` to the main query, but this will accomplish the limiting, and perhaps that is all he needs.  I figured he can add whatever sort he may need to add by himself.  I don't understand why adding the year filter would help either, but again I think he can tweak that.  The purpose of my answer is to recommend a filter table.

Answer (score 0):

Does `dim_make` have `PRIMARY KEY(make_id)`?  Let's see `SHOW CREATE TABLE dim_make`.

Does `ads_fact` have `INDEX(status, date_time)`?  Let's see `SHOW CREATE TABLE ads_fact`.

If it would be OK to `ORDER BY date_time DESC`, that would run a lot faster (after adding the above index).

If you are concerned about duplicate values in `date_time`, then, do

```
ORDER BY date_time DESC, ad_id DESC
```

If, after fixing the *first* page of your "pagination", you find that later pages are too slow, see my article on [*why pagination via OFFSET can be bad*](http://mysql.rjweb.org/doc.php/pagination).

Another issue...  You are verging on "over-normalization":

- `state` may as well be a 2-byte `CHAR(2) CHARACTER SET ascii` instead of a 4-byte `INT`.
- `fuel_type` can be either a 1-byte `ENUM('unk', 'gas', 'diesel', 'electric', 'hybrid', 'natural gas', 'hydrogen')` or perhaps a 1-byte `CHAR(1) CHARACTER SET ascii` with values like 'G', 'D', 'H', etc.

(I don't think the `JOINs` are your main performance problem; I think the indexing is.)

Comment: The "slight change" of adding `year>2009` destroys some of my answer.  Please check my answer without that clause, then decide whether to change the Question.  Or maybe start a new question -- The "best" answer will have to be different!